# Kotlin implement a method from an interface that's already present in super class

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have this interface:

```
interface Things {
  fun size(): Int
}
```

And I want to subclass a `List` and implement this interface.

```
class Cars : ArrayList<String>, Things {}
```

I get a compilation error:

> Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have
>   the same JVM signature (size()I): fun (): Int defined in
>   Things fun size(): Int defined in Things

I can get around the compilation error by changing the `size` contract to a `var` implicit getter:

```
interface Things {
    var size: Int
}
```

But then I get a long and complicated error that looks like a runtime error (`IllegalStateException`) but seems to happen when Kotlin is compiling :shrug:

I suspect I know why this is happening - `ArrayList` already has `int size()` and Kotlin now tries to add another of the same signature, but even if I'm right (10% chance?) it doesn't help much.

I'll also mention that it allows me to have `get` as part of the `Things` interface, which is satisfied by the list.  I'm guessing the `operator` operator let's this be just different enough to slide?

So anyway, no IDE errors, but when I build I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Concrete fake override public open fun <set-size>(<set-?>: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit defined in org.blah.Stuff[PropertySetterDescriptorImpl@673f2280] should have exactly one concrete super-declaration: []
File being compiled at position: file:///blah/Stuff.kt
The root cause was thrown at: bridges.kt:122
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:579)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:455)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1005)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1047)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:454)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concrete fake override public open fun <set-size>(<set-?>: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit defined in org.blah.Stuff[PropertySetterDescriptorImpl@673f2280] should have exactly one concrete super-declaration: []
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.bridges.BridgesKt.findConcreteSuperDeclaration(bridges.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.bridges.BridgesKt.generateBridges(bridges.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.JvmBridgesImplKt.generateBridgesForFunctionDescriptorForJvm(JvmBridgesImpl.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateBridges(FunctionCodegen.java:1041)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBridges(ClassBodyCodegen.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:68)
    ... 44 more


> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

Anything I'm missing.  I've spent most of my life in Java and am late to the Kotlin party.  Any workarounds, alternatives...  or is this a known thing?

TYIA

Comment: When I create a toy example `class C: A(), B { override fun f() { super<A>.f() } }`, it compiles. I guess the problem is related to the fact that `ArrayList` is a Java class. But honestly, I don't understand the reason (you are right that it's because `ArrayList` has its own `size()`, but my toy example too). A workaround for `jvm name clash` is to specify Jvm name explicitly, but Kotlin seems to not allow this attribute for interface methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because kotlin have extension val property for List: [size](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/size.html).

The first error says that you have two different kotlin "things" (method and property) which in jvm are the same. And the second error is because you have **val** implementation in `ArrayList` and **var** field in interface so your class `Cars` needs to implement both setter and getter but implements only getter (from `List val size`).

The solution is simple: just change your interface property to `val size: Int`

Comment: not only did the answer work, your short clear explanation was easily digestible.  thanks a ton